# Very slow speeds for Amazon Client VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, vpn

I've setup a Amazon Client VPN service in order to allow devs access to specific databases in VPC. I'm able to connect to the VPN (via OpenVPN and Amazon client), the IP is also correctly allocated, but the connection speeds are slow enough, that I can't be sure it works at all (~8 KB/s). The service on AWS also shows that the connections were made.

I'm running out of ideas as to what's wrong - I've seen some solutions about disabling TCP timeouts in linux clients, but that did not help me on Windows.

The specifics for my setup:

- VPC is divided into private and public subnets
- Client VPN is created in the public subnet, with security groups allowing access to the private subnet
- the databases are mongoDB hosted on EC2s, which are accessible via proxy/jump host (another EC2 hosted in the public subnet)
- authentication is done using a self created certificate using EasyRSA - I've uploaded generated "server" certificate for both server and client on the ClinetVPN service, and using a generated "client" certificate to authenticate (both are generated using the same CA)
- Client VPN CIDR is 10.0.64.0/22, and the endpoint CIDRs in authorization rules are: 10.0.128.0/20, 10.0.144.0/20 ,10.0.160.0/20

Below is my config file for the client:

```
 client 
 dev tun 
 proto udp
 remote cvpn-endpoint-XXX.prod.clientvpn.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 443 
 remote-random-hostname resolv-retry infinite nobind
 remote-cert-tls server cipher AES-256-GCM verb 3 
 <ca>
 -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
 -----END CERTIFICATE-----
 
 </ca> <cert>
 -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
 -----END CERTIFICATE----- </cert>
 
 <key>
 -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
 -----END PRIVATE KEY----- </key>
 
 
reneg-sec 0
```

I'd be very grateful for any insights!

Comment: Can you check your Internet speed using speedtest or similar tools?

Comment: @FranxiHidro Without VPN, I get about 30mbps, but with it, I only get timeouts. Both for connecting to the internet, as well as the internal resources on AWS.

Comment: Hope this can help you https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/client-vpn-fix-packet-loss-latency/
I'm using VPN SSO without any issues and in your case it's mTLS.